# Get image.url as atributte in a related model in django template

Tags: django

I have a ListView where a I want to list products. The problem is that I can't get the related image of these products as they are in a different model.

The model for products is:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='marca')
    name = models.CharField('nombre', max_length=40)
    description = models.TextField('descripción', blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50)
    active = models.BooleanField('activo',default=True)
    in_stock = models.BooleanField('en stock', default=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(ProductTag, blank=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField('última actualización', auto_now=True)
```

The model of images is:

```
class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='producto')
    image = models.ImageField('imagen', upload_to="product-images")
    thumbnail = models.ImageField('miniatura', upload_to="product-thumbnails", null=True)
```

To get both models in the template I used `context.update` in the view.

```
class ProductListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'product_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'products_list'
    model = models.Product
    paginate_by = 4

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({'product_images_list': models.ProductImage.objects.all()})
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        tag = self.kwargs['tag']
        self.tag = None
        if tag != 'all':
            self.tag = get_object_or_404(models.ProductTag, slug=tag)
        if self.tag:
            products = models.Product.objects.active().filter(tags=self.tag)
        else:
            products = models.Product.objects.active()

        return products.order_by('name')
```

Additionally, I created a filter to iterate both models in a forloop but I think is useless as I don't want to iterate both models, I just want to get the first image that matches the product's FK to show it in the template:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='zip')
def zip_lists(a, b):
    return zip(a, b)
```

The template I'm using is:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load humanize %}
{% load product_extras %}

{% block content %}

<div class="destacados">

    {% for product, image in products_list|zip:product_images_list %}
    <div class="collections coll-watches">
        <img class="foto" src="{{ image.thumbnail.url }}">
        <p class="prod-description">{{ product.name }}</p>
        <p class="prod-description prices"><strong>$ {{ product.price|intcomma }}</strong></p>
        <a class="boton-tr boton-tr-watches" href="#">Agregar al carrito</a>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

As you can see the problem is in `<img class="foto" src="{{ image.thumbnail.url }}">`. I know this is incorrect, but I don't know how to get the image related to the product through its FK.

I'm new i django (only two months) and I'm sure this should be easier, but I can figure it out...

Any help would be appreciated!!
Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define a get image url method in your product model as below

```
def get_image_url(self):
        img = self.productimage_set.first()
        if img:
            return img.thumbnail.url
        return img #None
```

and call it in your templates get_image_url

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much @bmons. I had to modify the method a little bit, but your answer gave me the clue I needed.

This is the final code:

```
def get_image_url(self):
        img = self.productimage_set.first().thumbnail.url
        if img:
            return img
        return img #None
```

When Using `img = self.productimage_set.thumbnail.first()` I get a RelatedManager error.
Anyway, I really appreciate your help!! Cheers